# Get <TH> texts into a tab separated string

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
table_with_headers = $(this.dom.table).find("thead tr th").map(->
  $(this).text()
).get().join("\t")
```

Can one write it nicer? I especially don't like the inner function in map syntax enforced by CoffeeScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CoffeeScript is not my forte, however I quite like this approach:

```
elements =  $(this.dom.table).find("thead tr th")
table_with_headers2 = ($(element).text() for element in elements ).join('\t')
```

This way you call out which elements you are going to process, and then use a list comprehension. In a style that is closer to JS than true CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 6):

You can use explicit find like so

```
$ 'thead tr th', @dom.table
```

and put some indentations instead of braces

```
table_with_headers = $ "thead tr th", @dom.table
.map -> @.text()
.join '\t'
```

Also try to use list comprehesion

```
table_with_headers = [
  $(th).text()
  for th in
  $ "thead tr th", @dom.table
].join '\t'
```

Comment: sorry, but proposed solution does not work.

Comment: @andi check updates

Comment: May I suggest renaming `elem` to `th`?

Comment: @200_success, done.